# Verifying the solutions of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to verify that $y_1(t)=1,y_2(t)=t^{1/2}$ are solutions of the equation $$yy''+(y')^2=0$$. Then I need to show that $y=c_1+c_2t^{1/2}$ is not a solution of the equation. I do not know how to verify the solutions. As for showing that
$y=c_1+c_2t^{1/2}$ is not a solution, I think I need to find the Wronskian of the solutions and conclude that since wronskian can be equal to zero, $y=c_1+c_2t^{1/2}$ does not represent the fundamental set of solutions. Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Amzoti is my thinking about the second part correct?

Comment: An interesting note, perhaps: we can rewrite this equation as
$$
\frac{y''}{y'} = - \frac{y'}{y} \implies\\
\frac{d}{dt}\ln|y'| = -\frac{d}{dt}\ln|y|
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom and also we can rewrite it as $\frac{d}{dt} (y y^\prime) = 0 $...

Comment: The option $(yy')'=0$ has the huge advantage of *not* dividing by $y$ and $y'$ and to be easily pushed further: since $(yy')'=0$, one knows that $2y(t)y'(t)=c$ for every $t$ where $y(t)$ exists. Now, $2yy'=(y^2)'$, hence $y^2(t)=ct+c'$, end of story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can find a nonzero solution of the differential by the following method.

suppose we write $y' = u.$ then we have $u' = -\frac{u^2}y $ these two can be combined $$\frac{du}{dy} =-\frac{u}{y} \to \frac{du}{u} + \frac{dy}{y} = 0 $$ which leads to $$u = \frac{2C}{y}\to y\,dy = 2Cdt \to y^2 = Ct + D $$

therefore, a solution  to $$yy'' = (y')^2 \text{ is } y = \sqrt{Ct + D} \text{ where } C, D \text{ are arbitrary constants.}$$

p.s. this validates(makes it easier to see) claude's suggestion of a change of variable $y = \sqrt z.$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

I think that the problem could be simplified defining $y=\sqrt z$.

Doing so, the differential equation just write $z''=0$ from which $z'=c_1$, $z=c_1t+c_2$ and $y=\sqrt{c_1t+c_2}$.

Comment: claude, check out my answer. how did you come up with the change of variable?

Comment: @abel. Just because $y=\sqrt t$ is a solution ! So I suspected something like that. By the way, your solution is nice $+1$. Chers.

Comment: thanks for all the upvotes claude. i just wanted you to look at a different way of solving.

Comment: @abel. I am always interested by other approaches and I use to enjoy yours; that' it !

Answer (score 1):

Obviously any constant is a solution of the equation, since the equation only contains derivatives. For the second term you get

$$y'(t) = \frac{1}{2 t^{1/2}}$$

$$y''(t) = -\frac{1}{4 t^{3/2}}$$

Finally, because of the square the equation is non linear, that is, a linear combination of the solutions is not a solution, hence $c_1+ c_2 t^{1/2}$ is not a solution. You can verify it by setting 
$$f(t) =c_1+ c_2 t^{1/2}$$ and plugging it back in the equation.